# Firestore rules for document field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm struggling within Firestore to set security rules for a document. With the RTDB is was possible to set rules for a specific object property and I'm trying to do the same with Firestore.

RTDB Code:

```
"users": {
    ".read": true,
    ".indexOn": ["profile/name"],
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write":
            "$uid === auth.uid && !data.exists()",
        "profile": {
            "birthday": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            },
            "name": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            },
            "banned": {
                ".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below the same code in Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/ {
            allow read
            match /{$user} {
                allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
                allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.id &&  exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.id)) === false

                match /birthday {
                    allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.id
                }
                match /name {
                    allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.id
                }
                match /banned  {
                    allow write: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userType > 3
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm writing security rules for a subcollection it's working fine. But for a document field it's not working. Is this not possible or is there a special `path` segment in the match reference? [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#path_segments) doesn't state anything about this.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by checking the `request.resource.data` property. As shown in this section of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).  You only need to match the document level.  You check the field rules with an `if` condition.

However, you are unable to control read access to individual fields.  A user can either read a whole document or not.  If you need to store private data, consider adding this to a sub-collection of the user document.

Here is an example

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
    // the name is not changed
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
                    && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That could work for writes, but that wouldn't work for reading. It also creates more spaghetti code.

Comment: For reads, you simply omit `request.`  There is an example shown in the documentation link that I sent you

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are doing with the `banned` field.  Can you update your question with the required outcome and post a comment back, so I can take a look?

Comment: The `banned` field should only be writable for administrators. So everyone can read certain fields of a user, some fields are only for logged in users and some for administrators.

Comment: The outcome is a document which is partially readable for guest, and fully for administrators. 

`allow write: if isAuthenticated() && (request.resource.data.banned is bool && isAdministrator())`

Where `isAdmininistrator()` is the following:

`function isAdministrator() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userType >= 1;
}`

Comment: With Cloud Firestore you cannot restrict reading of individual fields.  You can only allow / prevent reading of a document.  However, it is possible to control the writing of individual fields.  If there is private data that you wish to store, you should add a collection to the user document which can contain this private data.  I usually have 3 collection, `public`, `private` (accessible by the user) and `internal`.  You could add an `admin` collection, also.

Comment: Fair enough. But it would be possible to restrict the writing of an individual field. For example I want the user as a document to be read by everyone, all fields writable by the same user, except two fields. Those two fields (banned and userType in this example) should only be writable by admins. That could be possible?

Comment: This should work for you.  You'll probably want to copy your banned / userType to an `allow update` or change `allow create` to `allow write`.  Otherwise, no-one will be able to update the document.

Comment: Maybe this will help: you can access the target fields of an incoming write using the [`writeFields` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#writefields). So you can do something like: `allow write: if isAdministrator() || !('banned' in request.writeFields);`

Comment: Checking for both fields: `allow write: if isAdministrator() || !(request.writeFields.hasAny(['banned', 'userType']));`

Comment: @JasonBerryman I probably should change it to write. Another question, is it possible to check for data types? Noticed a similar line in the docs and tried to use it.
`request.resource.data.banned is bool`. But this fails. @JRLtechwriting thanks for that, hadn't noticed that function yet.

Comment: `allow write: if request.resource.data.banned is bool;` *should* work

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like this is now supported:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'visibility'
    // field set to 'public'
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public';
    }
  }
}
```

The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document.

---

To give a concrete example, in my case I needed to provide read access to a group only if the requesting user is in the **members** field (which is an array) of the **groups** collection. So I did this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isMember(userId) {
      return (userId in resource.data.members);
    }
    match /groups/{group} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && isMember(request.auth.uid);
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the json doc for `request` properties

Comment: @Santosh - As of now, the properties are: `auth`, `method`, `path`, `query`, `resource`, `time`. You can find the docs here: [Interface: Request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request)