# Firestore rules to write/update one particular field without auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to give write/update access to only one field from my firestore database collection without requesting the auth service. My rules for firestore is:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /businesses/{businessId} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My database structure for `businesses` is:

```
addedBy: string;
address: string;
category: string;
claim: boolean;
city: string;
email: string;
id: string;
likes: number;
location: {
    _lat: number,
    _long: number
};
name: string;
ocHours: [{
    day: string,
    from: string,
    status: string,
    to: string
}];
phone: number;
sponsored: boolean;
state: string;
status: string;
verificationCode: string;
```

I want to update only the `claim` field without `request.auth.uid != null`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919641/firestore-rules-for-document-field)

Answer (score 9):

rights assignments in firestore Rules as Ron says can only be applied to a whole document.
Nevertheless there is a way of allowing to write/update/delete/create a specific file and that is  by ensuring that the incoming change object has only the field you want to grant rights.
And you do that by:

1. Reading all keys in the incoming Object: `request.resource.data.keys()`
2. Ensuring that the only key in the object is `hasOnly(["claim"])`

---

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /businesses/{businessId} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["claim"]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps although the question was posted a while a go!!

Comment: `request.resource.data` seems to contain the entire document, and not just the attributes being written. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MoeSalih running into the same thing... is there a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this thread is still valid, but searching for a solution I stumbled upon the `rules.MapDiff` spec, that does exactly what you are looking for:

```
// Compare two Map objects and return whether the key "a" has been
// affected; that is, key "a" was added or removed, or its value was updated.
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```

See here for details https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this blog post](https://dev.to/chinchang/restrict-specific-fields-updation-in-firebase-firestore-ohp), `request.resource.data` does not contain only the updated fields, but the **entire future state** if the write would be successful.

So you could simply check if the field in the resource differs from the one in the request and, as the author neatly suggests, create a function like this:

```
function notUpdating(field) {
 return !(field in request.resource.data) || resource.data[field] == request.resource.data[field]
}
```

In your case, you would probably want to break your `write` into `create`,`update`,`delete` and the `update` could look something like this:

```
allow update: if
     notUpdating(addedBy)
  && notUpdating(address)
  && notUpdating(category)
  // ... put all fields here except 'claim'
  && notUpdating(status)
  && notUpdating(verificationCode) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is applied to the entire document. You can create a "claims" collection of documents identified by business-uid's and set it to `write` only so it is impossible for public to read the list but they can update the `claim` property. These documents could be boolean like

```
home/claimsCollection
    bizABC123
        claim:true
    bizXYZ123
        claim:false
```

Comment: But if I approach this solution then instead of one call I have to make at least three calls and as you know firebase will charge me more. 

Comment: If you do run up against such limitations, you will have succeeded in creating a break-out app and at that point billing won't be an issue :-) Firebase is effectively free unless your app hits mass utilization.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following function to be used to allow only one field to be editable:

```
function onlyField(field) {
    return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly([field]);
}
```

This function can be used as follow:

```
match /someObject/{document=**} {
    allow update: if onlyField('someFieldOfYOurObject');
}
```