# How to set path to a field in Firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My collection name is "users" and in that i have some documents created in random number and when i click that i get my fields as

**name** : john

**swimming** : true

**uid** : (auth.uid)

Since my document is created in random numbers i can't access that document directly as `request.auth.uid`

Now i want to know how can i write security rules to stop the user from updating his swimming field as false?

**EDIT**
What i have tried so far,

```
match/users/{document=**}
{
allow read;
}
match/users/{document=**}/swimming 
{
allow write : if false;
}


And


match/users/{document=**}
{
allow read;
}
match/users/{document=**}/{swimming} 
{
allow write : if false;
}


And 

match/users/{document=**}
{
allow read;
}
match/users/{document}/swimming
{
allow write : if false;
}
```

Comment: I suggest making an attempt at solving the problem, test it with application code, and if they don't work, include all that code in your question so we can see exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: @Doug_Stevenson i edited as u said

Answer (score 2):

For my 'users' collection, I create documents with the ID set to the UID of the user in question using the `set()` function instead of the `add()` function.  An alternative would be to do as you have: use the `add()` and explicitly set a `uid` field.

There are many blog posts that answer what you are after.  Googling for "firestore rules restrict updates of some fields" yields lots of results including:

- https://medium.com/day4/firebases-firestore-rules-how-the-f-af5821513025
- https://kushagra.dev/blog/ensure-missing-fields-in-firestore-security-rules/
- [Firestore rules for document field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49919641/firestore-rules-for-document-field)

Ultimately, in your rule you can compare the `request.resource.data.XXX` (field XXX in the uploaded data) with `resource.data.XXX` (XXX in the existing data in Firestore), and return FALSE if you want to block the user from updating field XXX.  You can also use boolean operators to enforce a no-edit rule on multiple field.

Comment: Perfect answer. Helps alot. I'm a new user i have upvoted you.